# Sms message display in textView and not use the Toast

Tags: android, sms

I have studied the SMS Messaging in Android from the mobiForge. Nice tutorial.
I can now receive and send Sms from my application.

However in this tutorial the received sms is displayed using the Toast class. But I want to display  the SMS in a textView.

Can anyone help?

Comment: can you link to the tutorial so others can benefit from this post? Also, please accept an answer both for you and for others who go through the trouble to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is, instead of displaying a toast the moment the message is receaved, doing a "textView.setText("smsContentEtc");